# MPEG 2 TS ISOMEDIA complaint

Tags: java, android, stream, mpeg2-ts

I record `audio` using `android` AudioRecord class with success and to make it play with all players i add AAC ADTS headers with success and concatenated all in `MPEG 2 TS (.ts)` file and it's able to play with all players (native an VLC).

But unfortunately this file is not `ISOMEDIA` compliant to dashing with `GPAC`. I try to look at a solution and i found that i need to add `PES headers` to my `ES stream`.

please can't someone know how to add PES headers on top of ADTS headers in MPEG 2 TS using java ? on code below ?

```
enter code here
private void addADTStoPacket(byte[] packet, int packetLen) {
    int profile = 2;  //AAC LC //39=MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectELD;
    int freqIdx = 4;  //44.1KHz
    int chanCfg = 2;  //CPE

    // fill in ADTS data
    packet[0] = (byte)0xFF; // conversion hexadecimal a decimal - il y a seize unités de 0 à F, on parle donc d'hexadécimal.
    packet[1] = (byte)0xF1; // installe l'entete ADTS dans MPEG-2 (0xF1) au lieu de MPEG-4 (0xF9)
    packet[2] = (byte)(((profile-1)<<6) + (freqIdx<<2) +(chanCfg>>2));
    packet[3] = (byte)(((chanCfg&3)<<6) + (packetLen>>11));
    packet[4] = (byte)((packetLen&0x7FF) >> 3);
    packet[5] = (byte)(((packetLen&7)<<5) + 0x1F);
    packet[6] = (byte)0xFC; // 0xFC est également correct si vous ne connaissez pas la valeur de la plénitude du tampon
}
```

Comment: PES headers are documented all over the internet. Including on Wikipedia.

Comment: hi guy i appreciate times u took to answers me . and sorry for my englis i'm french speaker. i read a lot of tutorilal about PES headers and TS packets . but my issues i about to know how to build and  headers using java code like Xuggler encoder but  only for MPEG TS otherwise how can i add PES packet on top of addADTStoPacket() method ?

Comment: I don't understand. The specification is public. Are you looking for help using java? How did you write `addADTStoPacket()`?

Comment: thanks for your support i widely read specification about MPEG TS and i finally create PES haeder and adaptation field header and TS header proprely buy i have a difficulty to insert PAT and PMT inside my TS header this is my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53047394/how-to-add-pat-and-pmt-in-mpeg-2-ts-header-in-java-code please can you try to look and help . thanks guys